# BlackBerry: Do I need to sign the build of each resolution separately?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have developed a **BlackBerry app** using JRE 4.5 for **multiple resolutions**. I have got the ordered keys for signing the build. I need to know do I need to **order and sign the build individually** for all the build of different **resolutions** or just need to sign the build of any one resolution and change the resolution folder for respective build and do **Project-> Build Project** in **Eclipse** for different resolutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must sign each time.  So change the assets folder, and build and sign and save, and then repeat the process.

There are alternatives you might consider:

1. include all the assets and choosing the correct one at run time
2. include the highest resolution image and scale the assets at run time.

Using either of these approaches you would require only one build, which makes everyone's life a lot easier.

Update, just thought of another alternative.  Have a simple program with basic assets and download the correct assets for your device the first time the app is run.  If these are large, the SD Card would be a good place for them.

**Clarification**

You use the same set of keys for all applications you build, they identify you as the developer, rather than being specific to one application.  But you must sign every build that you plan to distribute.

Comment: "include all the assets and choosing the correct one at run time", Yes that's what am doing. I have kept all the resources for different resolutions in their respective folder in my code's "Others" folder and at the time of building the project, I am just changing the content of "res" folder. So using a single set of keys will do, right?

Comment: "at the time of building the project, I am just changing the content of "res" folder".  This reads like you are choosing the assets at build time, not run time.  The option suggested above includes all the assets for all the different screens in the one cod file, and you only do one build.  Putting this another way, each time you build, you need to sign, if you want to use that build on a device.

Comment: Yes I am choosing the assets at the build time. Seems this isn't the right way. So I need to use new keys for each resolutions. Thanks

Comment: So I need to use same set of keys only but need to run the "Signature tool" each time on the build with different resolutions?

Comment: "need to run the "Signature tool" each time on the build with different resolutions?"  As noted in the clarification, you must sign every build that you plan to distribute.